# MySql - Select from a string concatenated with a comma

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation, where-clause

Suppose I have this MySql table:

| id | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | NYC |
| 2 | Albert | London |
| 3 | Joanna | Paris |
| 4 | Mike | LA |
| 5 | Norton | São Paulo |
| 6 | Pedro | Rio de Janeiro |
| 7 | August | Chicago |
| 8 | Carol | Miami |

So I get this string and I would like to filter people with these ids:
**"1,3,6,8"**
Sometimes the string I got is different: "1,5,4" or "3,6,5,8,1" etc.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: Ergest, it's something like this. I'm working with two tables:

SELECT
products
FROM
products_table
WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id FROM table_people WHERE city = "London");

Comment: @Vanderlei check my answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vanderlei based on your comment I will suggest not using a `subquery`, but a join because it performs much faster.

```
select products_table.id,products from products_table 
inner join table_people
on products_table.id=table_people.id
WHERE table_people.city = 'London';
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/61

Comment: Thanks, Ergest. That solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `WHERE IN (...)` construct in your query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (1, 3, 6, 8);
```

Comment: Tim, this gave me a hint. Thanks